# What happens when an default off-topic closing reason is deactivated?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, close-reasons, off-topic

On Drupal Answers, we have the possibility of defining three off-topic closing reasons. One of those is already set for us, and we can only deactivate it; it is not possible to edit it.

> Questions on programming, PHP, SQL, etc. that do not relate directly to Drupal are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

What happens if that closing reason is deactivated? Would the closing reason still be visible for the questions already closed for that reason?

I am asking because three off-topic closing reasons are few; in the case we see there are few generic programming questions asked on Drupal Answers instead of Stack Overflow, we could decide to change that closing reason with another one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would the closing reason still be visible for the questions already closed for that reason?

That's exactly what happens. The deactivated close reason will still be visible on the questions that were closed using it, but it won't be available for future questions.

If you're just making spelling or minor wording changes (that were hashed out on your meta first for best results), you can ping [one of us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) to edit the close reason for you instead of deactivating it completely.